# Portrait and Landscape launch images for iPhone 6/7/8+ and X

Tags: ios, iphone, uilaunchimagefile

I'm trying to support Portrait and Landscape launch images for iPhone 6/7/8+ and X. However, when launching in Portrait mode, I get the Landscape launch image instead. It works fine in Landscape mode. Below is my info.plist file and the files in my XCode project.

[image]

```
<key>UILaunchImages</key>
<array>
  <dict>
    <key>UILaunchImageName</key>
    <string>Default-736h</string>
    <key>UILaunchImageSize</key>
    <string>{414, 736}</string>
    <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key>
    <string>Portrait</string>
    <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key>
    <string>8.0</string>
  </dict>
  <dict>
    <key>UILaunchImageName</key>
    <string>Default-736h-Landscape</string>
    <key>UILaunchImageSize</key>
    <string>{414, 736}</string>
    <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key>
    <string>Landscape</string>
    <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key>
    <string>8.0</string>
  </dict>
  <dict>
    <key>UILaunchImageName</key>
    <string>Default-812h</string>
    <key>UILaunchImageSize</key>
    <string>{375, 812}</string>
    <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key>
    <string>Portrait</string>
    <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key>
    <string>11.0</string>
  </dict>
  <dict>
    <key>UILaunchImageName</key>
    <string>Default-812h-Landscape</string>
    <key>UILaunchImageSize</key>
    <string>{375, 812}</string>
    <key>UILaunchImageOrientation</key>
    <string>Landscape</string>
    <key>UILaunchImageMinimumOSVersion</key>
    <string>11.0</string>
  </dict>
</array>
```